# Is it normal for a used self adjusting clutch to be loose on installation?

Tags: clutch

Model: BMW E46 6cyl 3.0L

I purchased a used Dual Mass Flywheel, Clutch and Pressure plate all from the same donor car. Everything was visually in good condition and I could still feel the machining grooves on the flywheel. So I decided to use it on my car.

The pressure plate is a self adjusting type made by LuK. From the research I did, I found out I needed to reset the pressure plate back to it's initial setting before installing to prevent premature failure of the clutch. I also found out to install the pressure plate screws evenly in small turns to prevent the self adjust mechanism to ratchet itself. I did both these steps.

However, after installing the pressure plate, the clutch disc is loose and I can freely spin it. I thought after torqueing down the pressure plate, the clutch should not spin. Is this because I have reset the pressure plate to what a brand new clutch disc would be mated to?

I also read after installation upon the first press of the clutch the self adjusting pressure plate will correctly adjust itself. If so, should I continue with the installation? Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would assume that you are correct in saying by resetting the adjusting screws you would increase the space between the clutch and the pressure plate.  I think it will adjust when you start driving.    I f it were my car, I would have replaced the clutch and the bearings while I was in there.  But I think you're good.  As long as the parts you have are correct, there's not much that could be installed wrong.